# Android Location using FusedLocationProviderApi

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am attempting to use the FusedLocationProviderApi to get location data on my tablet but whenever I start the application I get the error

E/MainActivity﹕ Connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null}

I have no idea what is causing this error. I have a sort of off brand tablet which I thought might be causing the problem. The Model Number: DL701Q, Android version: 4.4.2 and google play build version 4.9.13

Here is my applications code, some things are commented out as I was testing trying to find the problem.

```
package temp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener,
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    Button bLogout;
    ImageButton bLogData;
    GPSTracker gps;
    TextView etLabel;
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FATEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e(TAG, "On Create . . . . .");

//        if(!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()){
//            finish();
//        }
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        etLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmailLabel);
        bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
        bLogData = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.DataLog);
//        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        bLogData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                updateUI();
            }
        });

        bLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                userLocalStore.clearuserData();
                userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class));
            }
        });

        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
    }

    protected  void createLocationRequest(){
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(authenticate() == true){
            displayUserDetails();
        }else{
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class));
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStart fired .............." + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
//        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.e(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.e(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Log.e(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude: " + lng + "\nLatitude: "
                            + lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "location is null ...............");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
//        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
//        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
//                mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.e(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.e(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
        }
    }

    private void displayUserDetails(){
        User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();
        String userdisplay = "Logged in as: " + user.username;
        etLabel.setText(userdisplay);
    }

    private boolean authenticate(){
        return userLocalStore.getUserLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="temp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "temp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should upgrade your `GooglePlay Services` services "app" on the tablet to higher version, say 7.5.74, in order to interface w/ client library version 7.5.0
See also [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en) for further instructions how to upgrade it

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize the play services didn't update automatically. Just assumed it was the current version.

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing do you want update google play services.
2. You need to add Manifest File this meta tag.